# why could not delete the nginx config when using openresty

Tags: nginx, openresty

I am using openresty `openresty/1.21.4.1` as the web server,today I copied the nginx config from `/etc/nginx/` to `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/`. Then I delete the config of nginx `/etc/nginx/`, but the web server could not access anymore. I using this command to show the openresty config:

```
[root@k8smasterone nginx]# /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -t
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
```

does the openresty using the nginx config? is it possible to make openresty using config from `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf`? where should I put the nginx config to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `bin/openresty` is an alias to the Nginx command. You can point to your config with `-p` or `-c` flags:

```
$ /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -h

Options:
  -p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /usr/local/openresty)
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: PREFIX/nginx.conf)
  ...
```